# JavaFX Polyline shape stroke width scaling

Tags: java, javafx, shapes, javafx-8, polyline

In my javafx application I need to draw very specific chart. I decided to create custom control for this purpose. On control initilization I'm creating `Polyline` shape using my data series items as point coordinates, then translate and scale it to fit in the desired screen region on every layout request. It works like a charm, even with 5000+ points, with only one fault - polyline stroke width scales too =( I can scale stroke width to emulate fixed width, but scale in my charts not always uniform. Is there any way to scale and transform only polyline coordinates, without affecting stroke width? One solution I can imagine - recalculate whole polyline when layout changed, but it smells bad.

Any solutions?

Comment: There is no easy solution to this as far as I know. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22048114/drawing-transform-independent-layout-bounds-in-javafx for my Approach to this.