# Drawing transform independent layout bounds in JavaFX

Tags: selection, scaling, vector-graphics, javafx-8, affinetransform

For a simple vector drawing app I am looking to implement a "Selection Box", that is a graphic representation of the layoutBounds of a Node.

Example:

[image: example]

Thanks to [jewelsea](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea) and his [BoundsExample](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1441960), I have a good understanding now on how to get the data for the box. The part I am struggling with is actually drawing the box on the scene, in a way that correctly respects the transformations on the nodes.

Correctly in this case means the bounds logical size get scaled with a node, but the stroke of the selection box stays constant. Meaning a selection box scales with its corresponding node, but the stroke stays unscaled.

I can think of two general strategies to implement such a selection box.

1. As a property of my custom node
   The selection box could be an internal details of my custom node with its visibility bound to the nodes selected state. In that case I would need to find a way to have nodes IGNORE the parents transformations, if that is possible.
2. Drawing selection boxes on top of the scaled nodes on a transparent pane
   In that case I would bind the selection boxes to the layout bounds of the scaled nodes, after applying the transformations of a node to its bounds. This does not seem to happen in JFX (even for 'boundsInParent') as you can quickly test in the [example](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1441960) by applying some scaling to 'group' in line ~122.

Modified example with scaling:

```java
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Control;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;
import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeLineCap;
import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeType;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;

/** Demo for understanding JavaFX Layout Bounds */
public class BoundsPlayground extends Application
{
  final ObservableList<Shape>     shapes             = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
  final ObservableList<ShapePair> intersections      = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
  ObjectProperty<BoundsType>      selectedBoundsType = new SimpleObjectProperty<BoundsType>(
                                                         BoundsType.LAYOUT_BOUNDS );

  public static void main( final String[] args )
  {
    launch( args );
  }
  @Override
  public void start( final Stage stage )
  {
    stage.setTitle( "Bounds Playground" );
    // define some objects to manipulate on the scene.
    final Circle greenCircle = new Circle( 100, 100, 50, Color.FORESTGREEN );
    greenCircle.setId( "Green Circle" );
    final Circle redCircle = new Circle( 300, 200, 50, Color.FIREBRICK );
    redCircle.setId( "Red Circle" );

    final Line line = new Line( 25, 300, 375, 200 );
    line.setId( "Line" );
    line.setStrokeLineCap( StrokeLineCap.ROUND );
    line.setStroke( Color.MIDNIGHTBLUE );
    line.setStrokeWidth( 5 );

    final Anchor anchor1 = new Anchor( "Anchor 1", line.startXProperty(), line.startYProperty() );
    final Anchor anchor2 = new Anchor( "Anchor 2", line.endXProperty(), line.endYProperty() );

    final Group group = new Group( greenCircle, redCircle, line, anchor1, anchor2 );

    // monitor intersections of shapes in the scene.
    for ( final Node node : group.getChildrenUnmodifiable() )
    {
      if ( node instanceof Shape )
      {
        shapes.add( (Shape) node );
      }
    }
    testIntersections();

    // enable dragging for the scene objects.
    final Circle[] circles = { greenCircle, redCircle, anchor1, anchor2 };
    for ( final Circle circle : circles )
    {
      enableDrag( circle );
      circle.centerXProperty().addListener( new ChangeListener<Number>()
      {
        @Override
        public void changed( final ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, final Number oldValue,
                             final Number newValue )
        {
          testIntersections();
        }
      } );
      circle.centerYProperty().addListener( new ChangeListener<Number>()
      {
        @Override
        public void changed( final ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, final Number oldValue,
                             final Number newValue )
        {
          testIntersections();
        }
      } );
    }

    // define an overlay to show the layout bounds of the scene's shapes.
    final Group layoutBoundsOverlay = new Group();
    layoutBoundsOverlay.setMouseTransparent( true );
    for ( final Shape shape : shapes )
    {
      if ( !(shape instanceof Anchor) )
      {
        layoutBoundsOverlay.getChildren().add( new BoundsDisplay( shape ) );
      }
    }
    // layout the scene.
    final StackPane background = new StackPane();
    background.setStyle( "-fx-background-color: cornsilk;" );
    final Scene scene = new Scene( new Group( background, group, layoutBoundsOverlay ), 600, 500 );

    group.setScaleX( 5 );
    group.setScaleY( 5 );


    background.prefHeightProperty().bind( scene.heightProperty() );
    background.prefWidthProperty().bind( scene.widthProperty() );
    stage.setScene( scene );
    stage.show();

    createUtilityWindow( stage, layoutBoundsOverlay, new Shape[]{ greenCircle, redCircle } );
  }

  // update the list of intersections.
  private void testIntersections()
  {
    intersections.clear();
    // for each shape test it's intersection with all other shapes.
    for ( final Shape src : shapes )
    {
      for ( final Shape dest : shapes )
      {
        final ShapePair pair = new ShapePair( src, dest );
        if ( !(pair.a instanceof Anchor) && !(pair.b instanceof Anchor) && !intersections.contains( pair )
            && pair.intersects( selectedBoundsType.get() ) )
        {
          intersections.add( pair );
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // make a node movable by dragging it around with the mouse.
  private void enableDrag( final Circle circle )
  {
    final Delta dragDelta = new Delta();
    circle.setOnMousePressed( new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
    {
      @Override
      public void handle( final MouseEvent mouseEvent )
      {
        // record a delta distance for the drag and drop operation.
        dragDelta.x = circle.getCenterX() - mouseEvent.getX();
        dragDelta.y = circle.getCenterY() - mouseEvent.getY();
        circle.getScene().setCursor( Cursor.MOVE );
      }
    } );
    circle.setOnMouseReleased( new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
    {
      @Override
      public void handle( final MouseEvent mouseEvent )
      {
        circle.getScene().setCursor( Cursor.HAND );
      }
    } );
    circle.setOnMouseDragged( new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
    {
      @Override
      public void handle( final MouseEvent mouseEvent )
      {
        circle.setCenterX( mouseEvent.getX() + dragDelta.x );
        circle.setCenterY( mouseEvent.getY() + dragDelta.y );
      }
    } );
    circle.setOnMouseEntered( new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
    {
      @Override
      public void handle( final MouseEvent mouseEvent )
      {
        if ( !mouseEvent.isPrimaryButtonDown() )
        {
          circle.getScene().setCursor( Cursor.HAND );
        }
      }
    } );
    circle.setOnMouseExited( new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
    {
      @Override
      public void handle( final MouseEvent mouseEvent )
      {
        if ( !mouseEvent.isPrimaryButtonDown() )
        {
          circle.getScene().setCursor( Cursor.DEFAULT );
        }
      }
    } );
  }

  // a helper enumeration of the various types of bounds we can work with.
  enum BoundsType
  {
    LAYOUT_BOUNDS, BOUNDS_IN_LOCAL, BOUNDS_IN_PARENT
  }

  // a translucent overlay display rectangle to show the bounds of a Shape.
  class BoundsDisplay extends Rectangle
  {
    // the shape to which the bounds display has been type.
    final Shape                    monitoredShape;
    private ChangeListener<Bounds> boundsChangeListener;

    BoundsDisplay( final Shape shape )
    {
      setFill( Color.LIGHTGRAY.deriveColor( 1, 1, 1, 0.35 ) );
      setStroke( Color.LIGHTGRAY.deriveColor( 1, 1, 1, 0.5 ) );
      setStrokeType( StrokeType.INSIDE );
      setStrokeWidth( 3 );
      monitoredShape = shape;
      monitorBounds( BoundsType.LAYOUT_BOUNDS );
    }

    // set the type of the shape's bounds to monitor for the bounds display.
    void monitorBounds( final BoundsType boundsType )
    {
      // remove the shape's previous boundsType.
      if ( boundsChangeListener != null )
      {
        final ReadOnlyObjectProperty<Bounds> oldBounds;
        switch ( selectedBoundsType.get() )
        {
          case LAYOUT_BOUNDS:
            oldBounds = monitoredShape.layoutBoundsProperty();
            break;
          case BOUNDS_IN_LOCAL:
            oldBounds = monitoredShape.boundsInLocalProperty();
            break;
          case BOUNDS_IN_PARENT:
            oldBounds = monitoredShape.boundsInParentProperty();
            break;
          default :
            oldBounds = null;
        }
        if ( oldBounds != null )
        {
          oldBounds.removeListener( boundsChangeListener );
        }
      }

      // determine the shape's bounds for the given boundsType.
      final ReadOnlyObjectProperty<Bounds> bounds;
      switch ( boundsType )
      {
        case LAYOUT_BOUNDS:
          bounds = monitoredShape.layoutBoundsProperty();
          break;
        case BOUNDS_IN_LOCAL:
          bounds = monitoredShape.boundsInLocalProperty();
          break;
        case BOUNDS_IN_PARENT:
          bounds = monitoredShape.boundsInParentProperty();
          break;
        default :
          bounds = null;
      }

      // set the visual bounds display based upon the new bounds and keep it in sync.
      if ( bounds != null )
      {
        updateBoundsDisplay( bounds.get() );

        // keep the visual bounds display based upon the new bounds and keep it in sync.
        boundsChangeListener = new ChangeListener<Bounds>()
        {
          @Override
          public void changed( final ObservableValue<? extends Bounds> observableValue,
                               final Bounds oldBounds, final Bounds newBounds )
          {
            updateBoundsDisplay( newBounds );
          }
        };
        bounds.addListener( boundsChangeListener );
      }
    }

    // update this bounds display to match a new set of bounds.
    private void updateBoundsDisplay( final Bounds newBounds )
    {
      setX( newBounds.getMinX() );
      setY( newBounds.getMinY() );
      setWidth( newBounds.getWidth() );
      setHeight( newBounds.getHeight() );
    }
  }
  // an anchor displayed around a point.
  class Anchor extends Circle
  {
    Anchor( final String id, final DoubleProperty x, final DoubleProperty y )
    {
      super( x.get(), y.get(), 10 );
      setId( id );
      setFill( Color.GOLD.deriveColor( 1, 1, 1, 0.5 ) );
      setStroke( Color.GOLD );
      setStrokeWidth( 2 );
      setStrokeType( StrokeType.OUTSIDE );
      x.bind( centerXProperty() );
      y.bind( centerYProperty() );
    }
  }
  // records relative x and y co-ordinates.
  class Delta
  {
    double x, y;
  }
  // records a pair of (possibly) intersecting shapes.
  class ShapePair
  {
    private final Shape a, b;
    public ShapePair( final Shape src, final Shape dest )
    {
      a = src;
      b = dest;
    }

    public boolean intersects( final BoundsType boundsType )
    {
      if ( a == b )
      {
        return false;
      }
      a.intersects( b.getBoundsInLocal() );
      switch ( boundsType )
      {
        case LAYOUT_BOUNDS:
          return a.getLayoutBounds().intersects( b.getLayoutBounds() );
        case BOUNDS_IN_LOCAL:
          return a.getBoundsInLocal().intersects( b.getBoundsInLocal() );
        case BOUNDS_IN_PARENT:
          return a.getBoundsInParent().intersects( b.getBoundsInParent() );
        default :
          return false;
      }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
      return a.getId() + " : " + b.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals( final Object other )
    {
      final ShapePair o = (ShapePair) other;
      return o != null && (a == o.a && b == o.b || a == o.b && b == o.a);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
      int result = a != null ? a.hashCode() : 0;
      result = 31 * result + (b != null ? b.hashCode() : 0);
      return result;
    }
  }

  // define a utility stage for reporting intersections.
  private void createUtilityWindow( final Stage stage, final Group boundsOverlay,
                                    final Shape[] transformableShapes )
  {
    final Stage reportingStage = new Stage();
    reportingStage.setTitle( "Control Panel" );
    reportingStage.initStyle( StageStyle.UTILITY );
    reportingStage.setX( stage.getX() + stage.getWidth() );
    reportingStage.setY( stage.getY() );

    // define content for the intersections utility panel.
    final ListView<ShapePair> intersectionView = new ListView<ShapePair>( intersections );
    final Label instructions = new Label( "Click on any circle in the scene to the left to drag it around." );
    instructions.setMinSize( Control.USE_PREF_SIZE, Control.USE_PREF_SIZE );
    instructions.setStyle( "-fx-font-weight: bold; -fx-text-fill: darkgreen;" );

    final Label intersectionInstructions =
        new Label( "Any intersecting bounds in the scene will be reported below." );
    instructions.setMinSize( Control.USE_PREF_SIZE, Control.USE_PREF_SIZE );

    // add the ability to set a translate value for the circles.
    final CheckBox translateNodes = new CheckBox( "Translate circles" );
    translateNodes.selectedProperty().addListener( new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
    {
      @Override
      public void changed( final ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observableValue, final Boolean oldValue,
                           final Boolean doTranslate )
      {
        if ( doTranslate )
        {
          for ( final Shape shape : transformableShapes )
          {
            shape.setTranslateY( 100 );
            testIntersections();
          }
        }
        else
        {
          for ( final Shape shape : transformableShapes )
          {
            shape.setTranslateY( 0 );
            testIntersections();
          }
        }
      }
    } );
    translateNodes.selectedProperty().set( false );

    // add the ability to add an effect to the circles.
    final Label modifyInstructions = new Label( "Modify visual display aspects." );
    modifyInstructions.setStyle( "-fx-font-weight: bold;" );
    modifyInstructions.setMinSize( Control.USE_PREF_SIZE, Control.USE_PREF_SIZE );
    final CheckBox effectNodes = new CheckBox( "Add an effect to circles" );
    effectNodes.selectedProperty().addListener( new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
    {
      @Override
      public void changed( final ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observableValue, final Boolean oldValue,
                           final Boolean doTranslate )
      {
        if ( doTranslate )
        {
          for ( final Shape shape : transformableShapes )
          {
            shape.setEffect( new DropShadow() );
            testIntersections();
          }
        }
        else
        {
          for ( final Shape shape : transformableShapes )
          {
            shape.setEffect( null );
            testIntersections();
          }
        }
      }
    } );
    effectNodes.selectedProperty().set( true );

    // add the ability to add a stroke to the circles.
    final CheckBox strokeNodes = new CheckBox( "Add outside strokes to circles" );
    strokeNodes.selectedProperty().addListener( new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
    {
      @Override
      public void changed( final ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observableValue, final Boolean oldValue,
                           final Boolean doTranslate )
      {
        if ( doTranslate )
        {
          for ( final Shape shape : transformableShapes )
          {
            shape.setStroke( Color.LIGHTSEAGREEN );
            shape.setStrokeWidth( 10 );
            testIntersections();
          }
        }
        else
        {
          for ( final Shape shape : transformableShapes )
          {
            shape.setStrokeWidth( 0 );
            testIntersections();
          }
        }
      }
    } );
    strokeNodes.selectedProperty().set( true );
    // add the ability to show or hide the layout bounds overlay.
    final Label showBoundsInstructions = new Label( "The gray squares represent layout bounds." );
    showBoundsInstructions.setStyle( "-fx-font-weight: bold;" );
    showBoundsInstructions.setMinSize( Control.USE_PREF_SIZE, Control.USE_PREF_SIZE );
    final CheckBox showBounds = new CheckBox( "Show Bounds" );
    boundsOverlay.visibleProperty().bind( showBounds.selectedProperty() );
    showBounds.selectedProperty().set( true );

    // create a container for the display control checkboxes.
    final VBox displayChecks = new VBox( 10 );
    displayChecks.getChildren().addAll( modifyInstructions, translateNodes, effectNodes, strokeNodes,
        showBoundsInstructions, showBounds );

    // create a toggle group for the bounds type to use.
    final ToggleGroup boundsToggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();
    final RadioButton useLayoutBounds = new RadioButton( "Use Layout Bounds" );
    final RadioButton useBoundsInLocal = new RadioButton( "Use Bounds in Local" );
    final RadioButton useBoundsInParent = new RadioButton( "Use Bounds in Parent" );
    useLayoutBounds.setToggleGroup( boundsToggleGroup );
    useBoundsInLocal.setToggleGroup( boundsToggleGroup );
    useBoundsInParent.setToggleGroup( boundsToggleGroup );
    final VBox boundsToggles = new VBox( 10 );
    boundsToggles.getChildren().addAll( useLayoutBounds, useBoundsInLocal, useBoundsInParent );

    // change the layout bounds display depending on which bounds type has been selected.
    useLayoutBounds.selectedProperty().addListener( new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
    {
      @Override
      public void changed( final ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observableValue, final Boolean aBoolean,
                           final Boolean isSelected )
      {
        if ( isSelected )
        {
          for ( final Node overlay : boundsOverlay.getChildren() )
          {
            ((BoundsDisplay) overlay).monitorBounds( BoundsType.LAYOUT_BOUNDS );
          }
          selectedBoundsType.set( BoundsType.LAYOUT_BOUNDS );
          testIntersections();
        }
      }
    } );
    useBoundsInLocal.selectedProperty().addListener( new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
    {
      @Override
      public void changed( final ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observableValue, final Boolean aBoolean,
                           final Boolean isSelected )
      {
        if ( isSelected )
        {
          for ( final Node overlay : boundsOverlay.getChildren() )
          {
            ((BoundsDisplay) overlay).monitorBounds( BoundsType.BOUNDS_IN_LOCAL );
          }
          selectedBoundsType.set( BoundsType.BOUNDS_IN_LOCAL );
          testIntersections();
        }
      }
    } );
    useBoundsInParent.selectedProperty().addListener( new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
    {
      @Override
      public void changed( final ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observableValue, final Boolean aBoolean,
                           final Boolean isSelected )
      {
        if ( isSelected )
        {
          for ( final Node overlay : boundsOverlay.getChildren() )
          {
            ((BoundsDisplay) overlay).monitorBounds( BoundsType.BOUNDS_IN_PARENT );
          }
          selectedBoundsType.set( BoundsType.BOUNDS_IN_PARENT );
          testIntersections();
        }
      }
    } );
    useLayoutBounds.selectedProperty().set( true );

    final WebView boundsExplanation = new WebView();
    boundsExplanation
        .getEngine()
        .loadContent(
            "<html><body bgcolor='darkseagreen' fgcolor='lightgrey' style='font-size:12px'><dl>"
                + "<dt><b>Layout Bounds</b></dt><dd>The boundary of the shape.</dd><br/>"
                + "<dt><b>Bounds in Local</b></dt><dd>The boundary of the shape and effect.</dd><br/>"
                + "<dt><b>Bounds in Parent</b></dt><dd>The boundary of the shape, effect and transforms.<br/>The co-ordinates of what you see.</dd>"
                + "</dl></body></html>" );
    boundsExplanation.setPrefWidth( 100 );
    boundsExplanation.setMinHeight( 130 );
    boundsExplanation.setMaxHeight( 130 );
    boundsExplanation.setStyle( "-fx-background-color: transparent" );

    // layout the utility pane.
    final VBox utilityLayout = new VBox( 10 );
    utilityLayout
        .setStyle( "-fx-padding:10; -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, lightblue, derive(lightblue, 20%));" );
    utilityLayout.getChildren().addAll( instructions, intersectionInstructions, intersectionView,
        displayChecks, boundsToggles, boundsExplanation );
    utilityLayout.setPrefHeight( 530 );
    reportingStage.setScene( new Scene( utilityLayout ) );
    reportingStage.show();

    // ensure the utility window closes when the main app window closes.
    stage.setOnCloseRequest( new EventHandler<WindowEvent>()
    {
      @Override
      public void handle( final WindowEvent windowEvent )
      {
        reportingStage.close();
      }
    } );
  }
}
```

---

Since I am fairly new to JFX I wanted to ask for advice. Hope you find this problem interesting :)

Best regards, Oliver.

Comment: Please edit the externally hosted code into the post; doing so will make sure it remains useful even if the link breaks. My script [is not allowed to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/4751173) because of potential licensing problems.

Comment: I have inlined the code modified by myself. Am I allowed to inline the code by jewelsea as well?

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps clarifying the question, and I don't think their [license](https://help.github.com/en/articles/github-terms-of-service) allows it (though it could qualify as fair use? I'm no expert at all on these matters...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the SceneBuilder itself is the largest freely available JavaFX project that I know of, that has that excact problem already solved.

By studying the `com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor` package of the SceneBuilder [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u-dev/rt) I was reassured, that my second proposed startegy is the way to go.