# How to draw selectable, movable, and re-sizable rectangles on JavaFX canvas?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, adaptive-user-interfaces

Is there a way to allow the user to draw individually selectable, movable, and re-sizable shapes within JavaFX and/or canvas that I am not considering or aware of?

I am new to JavaFX (Java GUIs in general, actually) and am trying to devise a method of allowing a user to draw (click & drag) up to 100 rectangles on a pane/workspace/page.  I am also looking for a method to make this scalable, but keeping static proportions for now will be fine.  I have not found a great deal of comparable examples in my search, most of which explore only one of those options but leave out certain things I need to accomplish.  Usually they show pre-defined nodes or canvas shapes that aren't individually workable.  So I am trying to find the best method to accomplish this.

Drawing the shapes is NOT the issue, I know how to do that.  It's making them individual objects within the workspace (selectable, movable, re-sizable).

My current idea is to create a Javafx pane, then create 100 canvases within the pane as predefined layers which will be the same dimensions as the entire workspace.  Each drawn rectangle will occupy one of the layers/canvas.  Selecting each rectangle will involve a click event within the drawn rectangle within the layer allowing the user to edit the, (move, re-size, etc.)

The following Oracle tutorial is what I am going off of for this method of layering. http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/canvas/jfxpub-canvas.htm

I have the feeling that my working premise for this method is flawed.  One reason is it requires pre-defined number of layers.  Although I want to limit this anyway, it is not very dynamic. But mostly, it just seems convoluted.

My apologies for the lack of code, and for the the conceptual nature of the question, but I've been searching and experimenting (unsuccessfully) for a couple weeks.  Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Thank You

***Project Context***
I'm creating a basic form creator. The user (in creation mode) will drag a series of rectangles that are associated with corresponding objects indicating certain attributes, coordinates, and dimensions of each rectangle. This data will be saved and used (in form mode) for the placement of text fields for form use.  Wherever rectangle were drawn on the workspace, text fields of the same location and dimension will be placed on the form.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22048114/drawing-transform-independent-layout-bounds-in-javafx. It is somewhat similar to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method I can think of is by making a group, and adding rectangles to the group, on-demand. You can then attach transforms and mouselisteners to each rectangle, and have it so that the properties of the transform is updated when a drag is detected. I've put together a simple demo here. Use a right-click to make a rectangle, left mouse drag to resize, and middle mouse drag to move the rectangle.

```
Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1080, 720, true);
    scene.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED,e->{
        if(e.getButton()==MouseButton.SECONDARY)
        {
            //make a new rectangle
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100,100);
            root.getChildren().add(rect);
            rect.setFill(Color.CYAN);
            Scale scaler = new Scale(1,1);
            Translate locationCenter = new Translate(e.getX(),e.getY());
            rect.getTransforms().add(locationCenter);
            rect.getTransforms().add(scaler);
            rect.getTransforms().add(new Translate(-50,-50));
            //listen for left mouse drags
            rect.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, e2->{
                if(e2.getButton()==MouseButton.PRIMARY)
                {
                    //resize with left drag
                    double scaleX=e2.getSceneX()-rect.localToParent(0,0).getX();
                    double scaleY=e2.getSceneY()-rect.localToParent(0,0).getY();
                    scaler.setX(scaleX/100);
                    scaler.setY(scaleY/100);
                } else if(e2.getButton()==MouseButton.MIDDLE)
                {
                    //move with middle drag
                    locationCenter.setX(e2.getSceneX());
                    locationCenter.setY(e2.getSceneY());
                }
            });
        }
    });
```